# Condition MAX(date_x) = YEAR(current_date) Teradata, SQL

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I'm working on a dataset. I want to create a statement:

If a person has a observation with a MAX(date_x) = YEAR(current_date), then it will return TRUE(1) on all rows, also the rows last year and the year before.

If a person doesn't have a observation with a MAX(date_x) = YEAR(current_date), then FALSE(0) on all rows.

Is this possible? Big thanks in advance!

This is an example of how the output should look, because Mike and Ofelia has rows in 2021, then all their rows has the value 1

[image]

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you include a sample of your data/tables. However it is possible and I'll drop an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a subquery to get the Max date per person and then a case statement

```
SELECT
 t1.*
,CASE
     WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM MAX_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)
     THEN 'True'
     ELSE 'False'
     END AS CURRENT_YEAR_FLAG
FROM (SELECT *
      ,MAX(date_x) OVER(PARTITION BY PERSON) AS MAX_DATE
      FROM TABLE) t1
```

Comment: Thanks @TheWitherCode! I'm sorry for the poor format, I'm still quite new on stackoverflow.

It makes really good sense. I'm going with something like:

`CASE WHEN Year(Max(date_x) Over(PARTITION BY PERSON)) = Year(Current_Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Current_Year_Flag`